# MJQ - orientationchange never chanve the height of the div

Tags: jquery-mobile

i need to change the height of the 'content' div, for that i used this code, but it never works... any idea pls?

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function() { 
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if(screenWidth >= 768){
        var the_height = ($(window).height() - $(this).find('[data-role="header"]').height() - $(this).find('[data-role="footer"]').height());
        $(this).height($(window).height()).find('[data-role="content"]').height(the_height);
    }
});
```

especially i am using this for ipad, and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

if the orientationchange event is binding properly then it seems to be work... check by placing alert messages inside of bind ... i have done small example to change height by click event ( http://jsfiddle.net/reddyprasad321/zj9LV/ )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
    <div data-role="content" id="contentDiv">
    This is Content Div ....  
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and js:

```
$('#contentDiv').click(function(){
    $('#contentDiv').height( $('#contentDiv').height()+20);
});
```

and css to see the difference :

```
#contentDiv{
    height:20px;
border-width: 5px;
border-spacing: 10px;
border-spacing: 10px;
border-image: initial;
border-color: red;   
line-height: 34px;
border-left: solid 1px #95C864;
border-right: solid 1px #74AE3B;
border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
border-right: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
background:green;
}
```

and also check here for setting the height 
http://api.jquery.com/height/
​
​

Comment: @3gwebtrain : I think if the orientation change event is binding correnctly then changing the div height is not a big thing.(Please debug each line of code inside orientationchange function by alert or log.. so you can find whether the binding is proper and height is correctly finding or not)